# Make "assign using assignment rules" default to true on Case

Tags: case, assignment-rules

When editing a case, Salesforce displays a checkbox on the bottom of the page that reads "Assign using active assignment rules" in the "optional" section, but it is unchecked by default.

Can this be modified to be checked by default instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, go to the layout and click "layout properties" at the top and you should be able to set a default value.

[image: sample]

Comment: Neat, thank you! :)